# python - getting a colour value

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the default maps given here https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

I am looking to get the colours for the map RdYlGn - mainly the end red colour and the end green colour - so that I can use the colours in excel. Is there a way to get the colour value?

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with Excel. 2) Download the relevant .png and use a colour picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place to look would be the matplotlib code. I found the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/) and searched it for "RdYlGn". Among the handful of results is the file lib/matplotlib/_cm.py, which contains the following:

```
_RdYlGn_data = (
    (0.6470588235294118 , 0.0                 , 0.14901960784313725),
    (0.84313725490196079, 0.18823529411764706 , 0.15294117647058825),
    (0.95686274509803926, 0.42745098039215684 , 0.2627450980392157 ),
    (0.99215686274509807, 0.68235294117647061 , 0.38039215686274508),
    (0.99607843137254903, 0.8784313725490196  , 0.54509803921568623),
    (1.0                , 1.0                 , 0.74901960784313726),
    (0.85098039215686272, 0.93725490196078431 , 0.54509803921568623),
    (0.65098039215686276, 0.85098039215686272 , 0.41568627450980394),
    (0.4                , 0.74117647058823533 , 0.38823529411764707),
    (0.10196078431372549, 0.59607843137254901 , 0.31372549019607843),
    (0.0                , 0.40784313725490196 , 0.21568627450980393)
    )
```

That looks like RGB data... taking the first and last points and normalizing to the usual 8-bit scale (in other words, multiplying each value by 255), the start and end points appear to be (165, 0, 38) and (0, 104, 55). And indeed, using a color picker on the page you linked gives the exact same values.